# In my HTML code i dont find a line of code that change display of my page but that line of code is showing in Inspect Element

Tags: html, css

```
<h2><a class="label label-info" target="_blank" href="http://www.avis.com.pk/"> Avis</h2> </a>
 <h4> <span class="label label-primary"> Rent A Car Service</span></h4>
```

Inspect Element image is attach its showing that line , but my code doesn't have such line.

[image]

Comment: check if you have closed the anchor tag correctly.

Comment: clear cache.....

Comment: yes, recheck you both tag `a` and . the `h2` , are they closed properly, or maybe its when you put anchor within anchor tag.

Comment: You need to give us some more information! We can't help at all. Can we know at least how this html is generated? If you are using javascript? At least the HTML code

Comment: The HTML code needs to be closed properly. You need to close the `a` tag first before closing the `h2` one

Answer (score 0):

> You have errors, you haven't closed the tags properly.

[image]

> The tag `<a>` has to be closed first before `<h2>` tag.

```html
<h2><a class="label label-info" target="_blank" href="http://www.avis.com.pk/"> Avis</a></h2>
<h4> <span class="label label-primary"> Rent A Car Service</span></h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

You closed the tags incorrectly in first line here:

```
<h2><a class="label label-info" target="_blank" href="http://www.avis.com.pk/"> Avis</h2> </a>
```

`<h2>` is the tag that gets opened first and `<a>` is the tag that gets opened second. So, you have to first close anchor tag as `</a>` and then close the heading tag as `</h2>`. Like this:

```
<h2><a class="label label-info" target="_blank" href="http://www.avis.com.pk/"> Avis</a> </h2>
```